# Query with double inner join not working in Qt

Tags: mysql, sql, qt

I'm developing a query and I to select the following values `incidencias.idusuario, incidencias.fecha, usuarios.nombre, usuarios.curso, usuarios.grupo, padres.nombre`.

I've created the following query because the fields `padres.nombre` and `incidencias.fecha` are in different tables from usuarios.

The query is

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("SELECT incidencias.idusuario, incidencias.fecha, usuarios.nombre, usuarios.curso, usuarios.grupo, "
"padres.nombre FROM usuarios INNER JOIN incidencias ON incidencias.idusuario = usuarios.id "
"INNER JOIN padres ON padres.email = usuarios.idmail "
"WHERE incidencias.fecha >= :fechainicio AND incidencias.fecha <= :fechafinal");
QDate fechadesde = ui->dateEdit->date();
QDate fechahasta = ui->dateEdit_2->date();
int fechadesdeST = fechadesde.toJulianDay();
int fechahastaST = fechahasta.toJulianDay();
query.bindValue(":fechainicio", fechadesdeST);
query.bindValue(":fechafinal", fechahastaST);
query.exec();
```

Every is working as it should but the last value, `padres.nombre` is giving me the following error when printing it:

```
QMYSQLResult::data: column 6 out of range
```

However I printed the count of the columns returned and it's just fine, `6`

Comment: Number of columns reports as 6; are you trying to access them as 1-6, rather than 0-5?

Comment: Indeed, that was the problem, @TheDarkKnight why don't you post that as an answer so I can mark is at solved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL expects indices that start from 1, whilst code arrays are normally accessed from 0 to x.

Therefore, a value of 6 is out of range for 6 returned items; use indices 0-5 to access the returned data.